# How to write path in the node.js+express application correctly?

Tags: node.js, express

**Description**
For building my application I'm using webpack(if it is important remark).
I'm trying to create node.js+express application and give the static files via `express.static("public")`.

My simplified project structure is following:

```
project-folder


/server
---index.js
/frontend
---/assets
------other files
---index.html
```

When application is builded I get one new folder in the root directory with this structure:

```
project-folder

/dist 
---/public
------/assets
---------other files
------index.html
---bundle.js


/server
---// other above mentioned folders and files
/frontend
---// other above mentioned folders and files
```

**Problem**
So, when I builded this application - my static files doesn't find on the server.
Ok, then I tryed to change `express.static("public")` to the `express.static(path.resolve("dist", "public"))`. And now it works.
*Now I understand*, that in the index.js all my routes are calculating **regarding this particular file**(index.js - which is not builded).

But, the problem is that - when I will host my site - I will have no the dist folder on the hosting. In other words, I need to compute the path to the public folder(and other files), relative to builded script(`bundle.js` file).

**Question**
What should I do? Or what do I misunderstand?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, I didn't need to build my application using webpack.
I just needed to upload my local server to the hosting and then to run this one.